# Python API/Lib for Datomic

Tags: python, datomic

does anyone know if there is a python implementation/API/Library or anything for Datomic.
Or any way to interact with a Datomic Database from Python ?

I've tried looking on the official Datomic Docs but nothing is explained. I would prefer to avoid Presto.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not at a stage where I can provide code

Answer (score 1):

From [their documentation](https://docs.datomic.com/pro/reference/languages.html), I've seen that they only have support for JVM languages. Non-JVM languages should use the HTTP Rest API, however it is deprecated according to their [own docs](https://docs.datomic.com/pro/api/rest.html)

There're also [some libraries referenced](https://docs.datomic.com/pro/reference/languages.html#third-party-libraries) in the docs for JS, Python, etc. but none of them seems to be maintained anymore.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34523949)

Comment: @dpapadopoulos of course I am providing an answer, I'm providing with the REST API for non-JVM languages (such as Python) and link to the libraries for Python (among other languages) clarifying that those libraries are out of date, which is what he asked for. What do you mean that I am not providing an answer?